# Failed to serialize SSO request dictionary for interactive token request

Tags: msal

I am trying to use MSAL with iOS 12 OBJ-C. I configure a MSALAADAuthority (https://login.microsoftonline.com/<< id here >>) and MSALPublicClientApplicationConfig with that Authority and a client id + redirectURI to the deep link for the app. I then create the MSALInteractiveTokenParameters with the scope I need. However, when it attempts acquireTokenWithParameters I get the following error.

```
Error Domain=MSALErrorDomain Code=-50000 "(null)" UserInfo={MSALErrorDescriptionKey=Failed to serialize SSO request dictionary for interactive token request, MSALInternalErrorCodeKey=-42008, MSALCorrelationIDKey=...}
```

pod has installed 1.2.5, not sure why it's not using 1.2.18 but that's another story.

Any thoughts about why I'm getting this error? NB I downloaded the Swift sample and it works fine with the same endpoint settings.

Answer (score 0):

I'd missed the step about adding the shared keychain capability. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc#adding-msal-to-your-project